# IsPostback Customized

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

I am trying to create my 'custom IsPostBack', all I did was create a bool property,

```
bool test;
public bool MyPostBack
{
    get{ test = Page.IsPostBack; return test; }
    set{ test = value; }
}
```

when debugging, having set, eg, value to false, when test is true, after pressing F11, test remains as it is! I find this very strange. Do you have any idea why? Thank you.

Comment: You need to call `MyPostBack` for it to change `test`.

Comment: you mean i need to do: set { MyPostBack = value;}

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create my personal IsPostBack, where I can get the true IsPostBack value but I can also 'set' it

Comment: You probably want `return test || Page.IsPostBack`.  However, this sounds like a bad idea.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you're doing in the property getter is reseting it:

```
test = Page.IsPostBack;
```

So, setting your MyPostBack property will have basically no effect because the value you set it to is overridden every time you **get** the property value.

You probably want something more like this:

```
bool test;

public bool MyPostBack
{
    get{ return test; }
    set{ test = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyPostBack = Page.IsPostBack;
}
```

The private variable (test) is initialized in the Page Load event to the value of the page's IsPostBack property.

Comment: the problem is that during the debugging, when walking through the code step by step, var test is not being properly set! I will try this out thank you very much

Comment: Right!  A variable initializer will set the value too early in the page lifecycle.  Page.IsPostBack isn't set properly when variable initializers execute.  You'll want to set the test variable in the Page_Load event.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you read the property, your getter resets the field to the original `Page.IsPostBack`.

Comment: OK now I get it, Thanks every one, due to the mistake in my code, when I was also GETTING it during debugging and trying to change its value,  it was also being reseted! This solved my problem and now I have finished my first e commerce website :) Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I like to suggest another way to do this.
Most likely that you would like to keep this in the session, so you can do the following:

```
public bool MyPostBack
{
   get
   {
        if (Session["MyPostBack"] == null)
            Session["MyPostBack"] = Page.IsPostBack;

        return (bool)Session["MyPostBack"];
   }
   set
   {
        Session["MyPostBack"] = value;
   }
}
```

That way, MyPostBack will always return a valid value, even if you did not initialize it. It will be available even prior to Page_Load (in Page_Init, for example).

I also think it would be better not to have a setter for it at all, but have some more calculations in the getter. Otherwise, from my experience, when setting its value in more than one or two cases, the code may become unreadable and not very easy to maintain.